# Getting the name of an image file in the ViewPager and displaying it in a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have several images in a `ViewPager` that the user can swipe, I need the name of the image to be display in a `TextView`. I am just leaning `java`, and image that the code will be something like this.

```
private void displayName (String name) {
    /*
    This is the code to get the name of the image that appears in the ViewPager
     */
    ViewPager swipeImages = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myImageSwipe);
    String backgroundImageName = String.valueOf(swipeImages.getTag());

    /*
    This is the textView where I need the name of the image file to display
     */
    TextView imageNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameImage);
    imageNameTextView.setText(name);

    displayName(backgroundImageName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting image file name to the image view ?  if so you can set the same name to text View.

```
   imageNameTextView.setText(backgroundImageName);
```